# Is there a way to override this message in my outlook plugin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, office365, outlook-addin

I am developing an outlook plugin that will be distributed among several users and I keep getting a message saying that "A program is trying to access e-mail address information stored in outlook."

Is there a way for me to disable this on every machine that downloads my plugin or disable it for my specific plugin? The program is written in c#

Many thanks

[the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbSFJ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should never get that prompt in an Outlook addin as long as you use the `Outlook.Application` object passed to your addin. Never create a new instance of that object.

To work around that prompt (not that you need to) see http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52 for the detailed list of your options.

Comment: so using something like:

'Outlook.Application application = new Outlook.Application();'
Outlook.Explorer explorer = application.ActiveExplorer();
Outlook.Folder folder = explorer.CurrentFolder as Outlook.Folder;
Outlook.View view = explorer.CurrentView as Outlook.View;
Outlook.Selection selection = explorer.Selection;
object selectItem = selection[1];
Outlook.AppointmentItem apptItem = selectItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem;'

is not valid?

Comment: I no longer get the warning after installing Microsoft Security Essentials. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Do **not** use "new Outlook.Application()" in a COM addin. The secure (no prompts) version of Outlook.Application is passed to your addin when OnConnection is called.

Comment: what should I change that particular part to? Thanks

Comment: is this a VSTO or a straight COM addin?

Comment: this is a VSTO addin

Comment: Use Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.